# Vector field on $S^2$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, inverse-function, stereographic-projections

Given the two charts for the stereographic projection from the north and south poles respectively:

$$ \phi_N(x,y,z)= \frac{1}{1-z}(u,v)$$

$$ \phi_S(x,y,z)= \frac{1}{1+z}(u,v)$$

and the changes in coordinates:

$$ (u,v) = \alpha_{NS}(s,t)= \frac{1}{s^2+t^2}(s,t)$$

$$ (s,t) = \alpha_{SN}(u,v)= \frac{1}{u^2+v^2}(u,v)$$

how can we show that $\phi_{N,*}^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ prolongs itself to a vector field in $S^2$ with a unique zero?

Comment: Good-natured question: Are you happy that the vector field vanishes in at most one point, and you don't see why it vanishes at infinity?

Comment: I dont see how it vanishes at infinity, and by infinity you mean in the North pole of the sphere right?

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/628010/2451

Comment: Yes, infinity means the north pole of the sphere. One strategy is to calculate the differential of the change of coordinates, then find the image of $\partial/\partial u$ under that transformation; vanishing at the origin should be apparent.